# Aesthetics must either be length one or the same length

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot values and errorbars, a seemingly simple task. As the script is fairly long, I am trying to limit the code in give here to the necessary amount.

I can plot the graph without error bars. However, when trying to add the errorbars I get the message

`Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:Tempdata`

This is the code I am using. All vectors in the Tempdata data frame are of length 390.

```
Tempdata <- data.frame (TempDiff, Measurement.points, Room.ext.resc, MelatoninData, Proximal.vs.Distal.SD.ext, ymax, ymin)
p <- ggplot(data=Tempdata, 
        aes(x = Measurement.points, 
            y = Tempdata, colour = "Temperature Differences")) 
p + geom_line(aes(x=Measurement.points, y = Tempdata$TempDiff, colour = "Gradient Proximal vs. Distal"))+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=Tempdata$ymax, ymin=Tempdata$ymin))
```

Comment: Replace `"Temperature Differences"` with `TempDiff` and `"Gradient Proximal vs. Distal"` with `Proximal.vs.Distal.SD.ext`.

Comment: Never use `$` inside `aes`. Use the `data` argument of the geom to specify the data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the colour-variables between quotation marks. You should put the variable name at that spot. So, replacing `"Temperature Differences"` with `TempDiff` and `"Gradient Proximal vs. Distal"` with `Proximal.vs.Distal.SD.ext` will probably solve your problem.

Furthermore: you can can't call for two different `colour`-variables.

The improved ggplot code should probably be something like this:

```
ggplot(data=Tempdata, aes(x=Measurement.points, y=TempDiff, colour=Proximal.vs.Distal.SD.ext)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin))
```

I also fixed some more problems with your original code:

- the `$` issue reported by Roland
- the fact that you have conflicting calls in your `aes`
- the fact you are calling your dataframe inside the first `aes`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jaap! However, also after having replaced the variable names, I still get the same mistake...

Comment: @ChristineBlume can you include some data (preferably a `dput`) in your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot Jaap, it is working now! :) Have a lovely evening!